# Using default values in defined class in R

Tags: r, class

I am trying to define  class which one of its slots is a list.
The definition of my class is as follows:

```
setClass("myClass",
     slots=c(a="matrix", 
             b="matrix", 
             c="character", 
             d="list"))
```

`d` is a list of some parameters as follows:

```
d <- list(d1=c('as','sd'), d2=c(2,3,4), d3=5)
```

The number of elements in `d` is variable, i.e. in one object it may has just `d1` and in another object it contains `d1` and `d2`.

I want to define an object like this:

```
myObject=new("myClass", 
       a = matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=5), 
       b=matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=3), 
       c='first', 
       d=list(d1=c('ak','fd','sd'), d2=c(2,3,4)))
```

After defining `myObject`, I want to set `d3` in list `d` to its default value, but I do not know how can I do that. I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can be provided with a prototype

```
.myClass <- setClass("myClass",
     slots=c(a="matrix", 
             b="matrix", 
             c="character", 
             d="list"),
     prototype=prototype(
             d=list(d1=c('as','sd'), d2=c(2,3,4), d3=5)))
```

Code to use the prototype as a template updated by a variable `d` might be

```
d=list(d1=c('ak','fd','sd'), d2=c(2,3,4))
myd <- getClass("myClass")@prototype@d
myd[names(d)] <- d
```

The new class could be instantiated with

```
.myClass(d=myd)
```

One could expose this in a more user-friendly way by defining an `initialize()` method, or by writing a constructor, as

```
myClass <- function(a, b, c, d, ...) {
    myd <- getClass("myClass")@prototype@d
    myd[names(d)] <- d
    .myClass(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=myd, ...)
}
```

Having a list as a slot kind of defeats the purpose of using classes in the first place; maybe it's better to have explicit slots d1, d2, d3?